# Combine multiple str_replace statmenets

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So this is what I'm trying to do

---

There's a column named `Trend`. This contains one of the 3 characters in each row: `=`, `<-`, `->`.

Now, i'm trying to use `str_replace` to replace each one with an specific image tag.

Example:

```
$trendz = $row["Trend"];
$eq = '<img src="img/equal.png" alt="Equal Value">';
$equal = str_replace('=',"$trendz",$eq);
```

and the other two:

```
$ri = '<img src="img/rise.png" alt="Rising Less than 5%">';
$rise = str_replace('->',"$trendz",$ri);
$lo = '<img src="img/loss.png" alt="Dropping more than 5%">';
$loss = str_replace('<-',"$trendz",$lo);
```

---

Now, how can I turn all of these into one string that can be echoed into my table?

Thanks in advance !

Edit: Also tried this:

```
    $eq = '<img src="img/equal.png" alt="Equal Value">';
    $equal = str_replace('=',"$trendz",$eq);
    $ri = '<img src="img/rise.png" alt="Rising Less than 5%">';
    $rise = str_replace('->',"$equal",$ri);
    $lo = '<img src="img/loss.png" alt="Dropping more than 5%">';
    $loss = str_replace('<-',"$rise",$lo);
```

This just prints out one image

Made an array and made it work:
Final Working Code:

```
    $placeholders = array('=', '->', '<-', 'X');
    $valz = array('$eq', '$ri', '$lo', '$xxx');
    $eq = '<img src="img/equal.png" alt="Equal Value">';
    $ri = '<img src="img/rise.png" alt="Rising Less than 5%">';
    $lo = '<img src="img/loss.png" alt="Dropping more than 5%">';
    $xxx = '<img src="img/x.png" alt="Not enough data">';
    $loss = str_replace($placeholders, $valz, $trendz);
```

Comment: [**str_replace()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) Also can take an array as argument.

Comment: @Rizier123 Got it, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Used an array !

```
    $placeholders = array('=', '->', '<-', 'X');
    $valz = array('$eq', '$ri', '$lo', '$xxx');
    $eq = '<img src="img/equal.png" alt="Equal Value">';
    $ri = '<img src="img/rise.png" alt="Rising Less than 5%">';
    $lo = '<img src="img/loss.png" alt="Dropping more than 5%">';
    $xxx = '<img src="img/x.png" alt="Not enough data">';
    $loss = str_replace($placeholders, $valz, $trendz);
```

gg